# Rails form helper adding an associated model through collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, associations

I have troubles adding an associated model through a collection_select method. Here are my two models

```
class Signatory < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :bank
end
```

and

```
class Bank < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :signatories
end
```

I have some banks already added in my "banks" table and I want to add a signatory with the associated bank_id field populated through a drop-down list. Here the code of the form:

```
<%= form_for(@signatory) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :bank_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:bank, Bank.all, :id, :name %>

  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <%#-...   %>
<%= f.submit "Add signatory" %>
<% end %>
```

These are the relevant parts of my controllers:

```
def new
  @signatory = Signatory.new
end
def create
  @signatory = bank.signatories.build(signatory_params)
  @signatory.save
end
```

The console shows the following hash which is what I expect:

```
Parameters: {... "signatory"=>{"bank_id"=>"1", "first_name"=>"Al", "last_name"=>"Smith", "email"=>"Al@"}, "commit"=>"Add signatory"}
```

However, I get the error message undefined local variable or method 'bank'. If I add the line

```
    bank = Bank.find(1)
```

in the create action, it would work, obviously. How/When/where do I define the 'bank' variable? What am I missing in the controller to have the form pass the 'bank_id' attribute to the 'bank' variable and then save it into my signatory table? Thanks.

Comment: Show us the place where you add `bank = Bank.find(1)`

Comment: You are missing a closing parentheses `<%= f.collection_select(:bank, Bank.all, :id, :name %>` to `<%= f.collection_select(:bank, Bank.all, :id, :name) %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the bank variable from those parameters like this:

```
def create
  bank = Bank.find(params[:signatory][:bank_id])
  @signatory = bank.signatories.build(signatory_params)
  @signatory.save
end
```

But this is unnecessary. It's simpler to create the signatory directly, e.g.:

```
def create
  @signatory = Signatory.new(signatory_params)
  @signatory.save
end
```

The `bank.signatories.build` pattern you are following is more helpful when you know the bank from another parameter in the hash or URL and you want to supplement a parameter that was not present in the form. In this case the only available parameter comes directly from the form (`params[:signatory][:bank_id]`).

Comment: Thanks but I am precisely looking for a way to "know" the bank from another parameter once I submitted the information from the form.

Comment: You can find the bank with `Bank.find(params[:signatory][:bank_id])`. I don't think it's helpful in this situation though. I've updated my answer with more detail.

Comment: It is helpful. This is the syntax I was failing to find. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's incorrect use of collection_select helper here:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:bank, Bank.all, :id, :name %>
```

Rewrite as:

```
<%= f.collection_select :bank_id, Bank.all, :id, :name %>
```

Also where's the `bank` variable gets defined here:

```
 def create
  @signatory = bank.signatories.build(signatory_params)
```

Do you have some `before_action` which is not shown?